# missing angle brackets using newpxmath

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mathpazo

The `newpxmath` package (version 2013/12/12 v1.061) makes angle brackets vanish from math mode:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
  $\langle x \rangle$
\end{document}
```

This results in just “*x*” rather than the expected “〈*x*〉”.  Presumably the following messages from the `.log` file are relevant:

```
Missing character: There is no h in font zplsy!
Missing character: There is no i in font zplsy!
```

Can anyone suggest how to get those angle brackets back again, other than reverting to `mathpazo`?

Comment: It seems that `newpx` has already been fixed: the update should be available by tomorrow on TeX Live. I'll test it as soon as I'll install the update.

Comment: Yep! I reported the problem to [Michael Sharpe](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14871/michael-sharpe) as @egreg suggested. Within 45 minutes, Michael acknowledged the bug, fixed it, sent me corrected files, and said he'd send the fix to CTAN. Wow!

Comment: Good team work!

Comment: Absolutely. I tip my `\hat` to both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the last update to `newpx` has introduced a bug: please, report it. For the time being, you can use the corresponding glyphs in `newtx`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar \font=127 }
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
  <-> \npxmath@scaled ntxmia
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
  <-> \npxmath@scaled ntxbmia
}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersAbug}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersAbug}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\langle}{\mathopen}{lettersAbug}{165}{largesymbols}{140}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rangle}{\mathclose}{lettersAbug}{166}{largesymbols}{141}


\begin{document}
  $\langle x \rangle$ $\bigl\langle x\bigr\rangle$
\end{document}
```

The second formula is to show that the bigger symbol is correctly set.

[image]

---

## UPDATE

With yesterday's (2014-01-08) release of `newpx` (version 1.071), the problem has been solved, so the described patch is not necessary any more.